# my meshes leave an after image

Tags: 3d-view, artifacts

when im in viewport solid mode my meshes get covered with weird artifacts and leave after images. this only happens in solid mode, and switching to any of the other modes clears them.[image: here's the mesh before moving]

here's the mesh before moving
[image: this is it after moving around and switching angles]

[image: this is after switching to wireframe and having the afterimage cleared]

first image is the mesh before moving, notice the artifacts are just some weird green decals(?). Third is after switching to wireframe and having the afterimage cleared.

this happens after I import with the diffeomorphic plugin but it never happened before and I've been using the same plugin since 2.8 this is the first time I import since 2.93.
Any Ideas?

Comment: I've never used it, but there appear to be several versions depending on which version of Blender you are using. The one for Blender 2.93 (1.6.0) seems to be [here](http://diffeomorphic.blogspot.com/p/daz-importer-version-16.html).

Comment: I'm already using the newest version of the plugin.

Comment: You'll have to ask elsewhere in that case as this forum only deals with addons built into Blender, not third-party ones.